# How to track GPS location for charge on iOS device like Uber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps

My team want to make an iOS app like Uber, which can track GPS location for charge. But according to my experiment and real-test, the GPS location point is not always accurate, there is some deviation sometimes. (the accuracy is low sometimes). So what cane be done to do like Uber?
thanks!

```
_locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager  didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

if (location)
{
    //success, but there is some deviation sometimes.the accuracy is low sometimes
}
else
{
    //error
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GPS accuracy depends on location. If you are moving in a tunnel or parking lot, GPS accuracy will be extremely low. So you need to check accuracy before taking signals for calculation for eg

```
if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 63) {
// GOOD SIGNAL
}
```

You can design some filter algorithm to filter out signals depending upon your need.

Comment: Not perfect. if any obstacles like trees buildings. Is there a way to get accurate location

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your accuracy.

```
CLLocation -horizontalAccuracy and -verticalAccuracy will do that.
```

You can see people posted answers already.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337483/3840428

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24876562/3840428